# How to use downloaded samples in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sample

I have downloaded samples from SDK Manager .
Can any one tell me how to use those samples to create a project in android Studio.

I have tried

> **Import a android code sample**

in the main menu but its asking for download again.

Where will these samples be placed when i downloaded from SDK manager?
How can i use it to create a project?

Comment: Google no longer provide the SDK samples as a download. Now samples are imported from the online Google github repository.
[Android SDK Samples as Examples for Guidance](https://tekeye.uk/android/android-sdk-samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't import the android code sample from android studio, make sure that the path below is not empty :

> **path/to/sdk/samples/**

For example you should have android-16, android-19, android-21 folders which contains samples project.

**EDIT 1** : To find your android sdk path from Android studio :

Go to

> File > Project Structure > SDK Location

Then you will find your android SDK location.

Cheers !

Comment: I am not able to find the SDK path...
Where it will be located?? I have installed AD in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio